# Error: illegal start of expression for public final static int = schlachtschiff

Tags: java

I'm trying do set ships on a field, but something is not right with my code. It says

```
illegal start of expression
```

for  `public final static int= schlachtschiff`.

I want to prevent invalid inputs. I used some `while` loops but I'm not sure if that covers it.

But first I need to make the program run.

```
public class setship{

static char[][] attacker = {
    { '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
    { '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
    { '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
    { '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
    { '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
    { '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
    { '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
    { '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
    { '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
    { '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' }
};

public static void print(char[][] grid) {
    System.out.println(" 0123456789");
    String[] myArray = new String[]{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
                                    "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"};
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(myArray[i]);
        for (int j=0; j<10; j+=1) {
            System.out.print(grid[i][j]);
            if(j == 9) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Where do you want to place your ship?");
    int row, col;
    public final static int  schlachtschiff = 1 ;
    //public final static in = 2;
    //public final static in  Zerstoerer = 3;
    //public final static in  Uboote = 4;
    while(col<0 & col>10 && row<0 & row>10){
        System.out.print("Try again.");
        row = s.nextInt();
        col = s.nextInt();
        while (attacker[row][col]= '#'){
             System.out.print("Try again.Already an ship there.");
             row = s.nextInt();
             col = s.nextInt();
        }
    }

    for(schlachtschiff=1; schlachtschiff != 0; schlachtschiff++){      
        System.out.println("Col: ");
        col = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("row: ");
        row  = s.nextInt();
        String position;
        System.out.println("Position (l),(r),(o), (u): ");                                      
        position = s.next();
          if(position.equals("l")){
            for(int i =0; i<5; i++){
                attacker[row-i][col] = '#';
            }
        }
        else if(position.equals("r")){
            for(int i =0; i<5; i++){
                attacker[row+i][col] = '#';
            }
        }
        else if(position.equals("o")){
            for(int i =0; i<5; i++){
                attacker[row][col+i] = '#';
            }
        }
        else if(position.equals("u")) {
            for(int i =0; i<5; i++){
                attacker[row][col-i] = '#' ;
            }
        }
        else{

            return;
        }
        print(attacker);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think the effects of `public` and `static` will be on a variable declared inside a method?

Comment: Another hint: All of your `public final static int` variables should be declared as class variables.

Comment: Or keep them inside your main method but remove the `public` and `static`.

Comment: @Java the hut I would say at least come out with a basic design for your program first. Plan your classes (e.g. A class for Ship, a class for Player) and decide where you want to invoke your methods (via the main or keep them as a behaviour in the classes). Those instance method from your class shall not be declared as static. Plan it right and you will see everything starts to fall in place.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this inside a method. It need to be class level

```
public final static int  schlachtschiff = 1 ;
//public final static in = 2;
//public final static in  Zerstoerer = 3;
//public final static in  Uboote = 4;
```

Or you can do

```
int  schlachtschiff = 1;
```

If it need to be in the method.

```
 while (attacker[row][col]= '#')
```

this is not how you compare

```
 while (attacker[row][col] == '#')
```

Comment: Yeah, noticed my mistake right after posting :P Misread the `'` as `"`

Comment: Ok but if i put it under class level then it cannot assign a value to the variable schlachtschiffe, and the scanne symbol cannot be find. i wanted to do it with just int..but i have to use public final  static int...